# VBA macro not finding last row and is overwriting the last entry

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to macros and self taught.  I wrote the following code which seemed to be working fine, but today,  instead of finding the next row it is overwriting the last entry.

The purpose of the macro is to update a central log of orders from an order form.  The macro needs to unprotect the log, update it with the new order and protect the log again.

```
Sub another_workbook()

Dim wbMaster As Workbook
Dim wbLocal As Workbook
Dim masterNextRow As Long

Set wbLocal = ThisWorkbook

Set wbMaster = Workbooks.Open("I:\GT Month End\Bookkeeper\Project Abacus\Forecasting and Invoicing MASTERTEST.xlsm")

masterNextRow = wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Range("A" & wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
 
Worksheets("Invoicing").Unprotect "1312"
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 1).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("C3").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 2).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("I3").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 3).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("N3").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 4).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("F5").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 5).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("F9").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 6).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("F11").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 7).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("F19").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 8).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("F27").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 9).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("H27").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 10).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("A27").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 11).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("C27").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 12).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("H27").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 13).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("M27").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 14).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("F38").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 15).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("N38").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 16).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("C32").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 17).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("D99").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 19).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("M95").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 21).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("D95").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 20).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("M97").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 24).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("D97").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 29).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("F36").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 30).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("F17").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 31).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("F13").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 32).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("F15").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 33).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("F40").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 34).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("M21").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 35).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("N40").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 36).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("H32").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 37).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("L32").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 38).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("F34").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing").Cells(masterNextRow, 39).Value = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form").Range("K34").Value
Worksheets("Invoicing").Protect "1312"
wbMaster.Close True

MsgBox "Input saved."     

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are not adding anything in column A `masterNextRow` will not update - perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: If you step through your code with `F8`, do you see the correct row-value, if not, is there something in the last row's A-value like SJR recommended?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally when finding the next row you're using a column which is guaranteed to have content.  If that's not the case you can add a loop to make sure you're not overwriting anything.

Using variables for your worksheets will make your code less bulky and more maintainable.

```vb
Sub another_workbook()
    Const PW = "1312"  'use Const for fixed values
    Dim wbMaster As Workbook, wbLocal As Workbook
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, rwDest As Range
    
    Set wbLocal = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSrc = wbLocal.Worksheets("Placement Form") 'source sheet

    Set wbMaster = Workbooks.Open("I:\GT Month End\Bookkeeper\Project Abacus\Forecasting and Invoicing MASTERTEST.xlsm")
    Set wsDest = wbMaster.Worksheets("Invoicing")    'destination sheet
    
    Set rwDest = wsDest.Range("A" & wsDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow
    'check this row is really empty!
    Do While Application.CountA(rwDest) > 0 'if any content in this row
        Set rwDest = rwDest.Offset(1)       '... go to next row
    Loop
     
    wsDest.Unprotect "1312"
    rwDest.Cells(1).Value = wsSrc.Range("C3").Value
    rwDest.Cells(2).Value = wsSrc.Range("I3").Value
    'etc etc
    wsDest.Protect "1312"
    wbMaster.Close True
    
    MsgBox "Input saved."

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of looping, wouldn't .Find would be a better option to find the last row as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba/11169920#11169920)

Comment: Yes that's fine too!  I sometimes use the loop if I'm anticipating not having to loop much (ie. *sometimes* there's a missing value in the column being used with `End(xlUp)`)

Comment: Thanks all soooo much for taking the time to answer.  The problem was I wasn't putting anything in column A.  All sorted and working now,  Such a steep learning curve!!!

Comment: Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.